# class of vector based on std::vector

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

I want to make my own vector class basing on std::vector.
Everything seems to be easy, but I get an error even from the constructor.
The class (minimum example) is as follow:

```
#include<vector>

template<typename T>
class vec {

public:

vec(unsigned int size){vec_(size);}

private:
std::vector<T> vec_;            
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vec<int> v1(3);

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int, std::allocator >) (unsigned int&)’
|         vec(unsigned int size){vec_(size);}

I cannot believe this little simple piece of code does not work.
Do you know why?

Comment: `vec_(size);` attempts to call an overloaded `operator()` on `std::vector`, which it doesn't have. `vec_.resize(size);` would work, but suggestion in the answer below is better.

Comment: If there is one piece of syntax of which beginners seem completely unaware it is the *member initializer list*.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
vec(unsigned int size) : vec_(size) {}
```

What you wrote is trying to call the vector as if it were a function, but it has no `operator()()`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I must construct the vec_ member. Many thanks.